# iBeacons issue while monitoring 2 or more regions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ibeacon

In my `iBeaconReceiver` app i was trying to monitor more that 1 region, and i used this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize location manager and set ourselves as the delegate and beacons dictionary
    _beacons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"6C1AA496-1653-403D-BD1E-7F630AA6F254"] major: 1 minor: 1 identifier: @"region1"];

    self.myBeaconRegion2 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"6C1AA496-1653-403D-BD1E-7F630AA6F254"] major: 1 minor: 2 identifier: @"region2"];

    NSLog(@"startMonitoring");
    // Tell location manager to start monitoring for the beacon region
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion2];

    _myBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
    _myBeaconRegion2.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;


    // Check if beacon monitoring is available for this device
    if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Monitoring not available" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; [alert show]; return;
    }

}
```

and then i start ranging for beacons

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
        if([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"region1"])
            [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
        else if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"region2"])
            [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion2];
    }
}
```

Now here's my problem, i created a simple `UITableView` displaying the beacons in the range of my device in this way

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    //NSLog(@"didRangeBeacons");
    [_beacons removeAllObjects];

    NSArray *immediateBeacons = [beacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"proximity = %d", CLProximityImmediate]];
    if([immediateBeacons count])
        [_beacons setObject:immediateBeacons forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CLProximityImmediate]];

    NSArray *nearBeacons = [beacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"proximity = %d", CLProximityNear]];
    if([nearBeacons count])
        [_beacons setObject:nearBeacons forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CLProximityNear]];

    NSArray *farBeacons = [beacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"proximity = %d", CLProximityFar]];
    if([farBeacons count])
        [_beacons setObject:farBeacons forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CLProximityFar]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

using the `_beacons` dictionary.
Here is my scenario:

First of all i have to say i'm using an iPad as iBeacon antenna able to broadcast alternatively `region1` or `region2`.

1. Start broadcasting `region1`, everything is ok, my `UITableView` is filled with that beacon's `UUID`
2. Stop broadcasting `region1`, start `region2`, everything is ok, my UITabelView shows me now the `region2 UUID`
3. Stop `region2` and go back to broadcast `region1`, `UITableView` is empty!No beacon is to be found
4. Stop `region1` and restart `region2` now `region2 UUID` is shown in my `UITableView`. From this point only `region2` is listened by my app, **PLUS** my `UITableView` trembles ( meaning it's jerky)!!!, as if every half second it reloads all the UI (thing that does not happen for example in point 1 and 2)

I have read some threads about this problem and the users solved by using different identifiers for each regions, but i think I AM using different identifiers, so i don't understand where the problem is! It looks like whenever it enters `region2` it forgets about `region1`.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues and, in my case, it's been because the callback to `didExitRegion:` isn't happening in a timely fashion. If there's no call to `didExitRegion:` then I *believe* the call to `didEnterRegion:` never happens and therefore you're not getting any data. The documentation is sparse on this subject since the API is still fairly new.

The solution of using different UUID Proximity ID's is an option as you suggested, though its frustrating to have to do this when Major/Minor should be enough of a differentiation. This is supported somewhat by the docs on Beacons saying that a single 'use' should use a single UUID. So for instance a chain of shops would use UUID to identify company, Major to identify the store and minor to identify location within the store.

Have you filed a bug in Radar? I would advise it as quantity matters where these things are concerned.

Comment: Yeah what you said gave me the idea that you can't `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` for multiple regions at the same time, in my case whenever i entered `region2` i started ranging for that region, stopping listening for `region1` and, as you said, never switch back!I'll try to move this method elsewhere the avoid the problem of `didEnter/didExit` and see how it works. Anyway i used multiple regions for a specific reason, that is i need my app to notify me when it's in background,and the only way to receive multiple notification is to listen for multiple regions (if beacons are near one another)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `locationManager: didRangeBeacons: inRegion:` method gets called independently for each region you are ranging.  So during times when iOS provides info about beacons in both of the two regions, **the method will get called once per second for *each* of the regions.**

This is a problem with the code shown because of the line `[_beacons removeAllObjects]` will clear out the dictionary at the start of each callback.  Consider that one of the callbacks can contain an empty beacon array.  When ranging both regions, the timing of the calls is indeterminate. So you may get a callback with a list of beacons, display it, then get another callback a tiny fraction of a second later with an empty `beacons` array, causing the first array to never be shown.  Similarly, when two regions are showing beacons, the display may flicker depending on the timing of the callbacks.

**The solution is to not clear the dictionary at the start of each callback.**  Instead, you must maintain a different dictionary containing timestamps for the times each beacon was last seen, and periodically remove any beacons that have not been seen in a few seconds from your display.

Comment: Clearing the dictionary was good for me because in the cell i also printed the estimated distance, in this way i needed a continuous update, but this was only for test purposes, I understood your point so i thinks it can fix it! So the device can `range beacons` for multiple regions at the same time?

Comment: Yes, ranging multiple regions works fine.  But it does complicate maintaining a single list of beacons in the UI because you get a different callback once per second for each region.  I am the author of the free Locate for iBeacon iOS app. And what I describe is exactly how that app successfully ranges for multiple regions.

Comment: yeah i'll work to solve all my issues with your advices, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things to consider when ranging beacons in iOS:

1. For each CLBeaconRegion you have defined (and called startMonitoringForRegion for) you will get the callback didRangeBeacons once every second as davidGYoung has said. This happens whenever you are inside the beacon region(s) you are currently monitoring for.
2. When your beacon signal goes away (by either moving outside the region OR simply turning OFF your beacon transmitter as is the case above), you will CONTINUE to get didRangeBeacon callbacks for approx 30 seconds while iOS figures out you are no longer inside the beacon region. I assume this is on purpose to avoid annoying "jitter" in the callbacks (although they still happen!). Note if this occurs, your didRangeBeacon callbacks will show RSSI = 0 of course.
3. Once iOS determines you have truly exited the beacon region, you will get the didExitRegion callback from locationManager.

--> So you can see that by simply turning on/off your transmitter you won't immediately see your beacon detector switch between regions, instead you should see TWO regions (one with RSSI = 0 and one with non-zero RSSI) for approx 30 seconds.

In your case I believe davidGYoung is again correct in assuming your having a problem with your arrays being cleared out each time. To avoid presentation layer problems you should double-buffer your arrays (one for each beacon region detected, and another, separate array for the UI table view). I've done this in the Zatar RDM iphone app and it works fine and has been tested with over 10 simultaneous beacons without any problems.